# Hermitian of a square Matrix in multi-dimensional numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

How to obtain the matrix Hermitian for a 2D matrix in a multi dimension np.array for example F has (3, 2, 2, 2) shape, the first two dimensions represent items in a certain category, the data is a 2D matrix exists in the last two dimensions (2*2):

```
import numpy as np
F=np.array([[[[  1+2.j, 2-1.j],[1+2.j, 2-1.j]],
    [[  0,  2+1.j],[0, 3-1.j]]],

   [[[  1+2.j, 2-1.j],[ 1+2.j, 2-1.j]],
    [[  0,  2+1.j],[ 0, 3-1.j]]],

  [[[  1+2.j, 2-1.j],[ 1+2.j, 2-1.j]],
    [[  0,  2+1.j],[ 0, 3-1.j]]]])
```

So the output should be the Hermitian of all 2*2 matrices while the output should has same shape as F:

```
F_Herm=np.array([[[[  1-2.j, 1-2.j],[2+1.j, 2+1.j]],
        [[  0,  0],[2-1.j, 3+1.j]]],

       [[[  1-2.j, 1-2.j],[2+1.j, 2+1.j]],
        [[  0,  0],[ 2-1.j, 3+1.j]]],

      [[[  1-2.j, 1-2.j],[ 2+1.j, 2+1.j]],
        [[  0,  0],[2-1.j, 3+1.j]]]])
```

So F_Herm.shape should be equal (3, 2, 2, 2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could compute conjugate of transpose

```py
# Just an example
A=(np.arange(24)+1j*np.arange(24)).reshape(3,2,2,2)

# Swap 2 tast axes (so transpose each 2D matrix A[i,j]), and conjugate
AH = np.swapaxes(-1,-2).conj()
```

Here

```
A=array([[[[ 0. -0.j,  2. -2.j],
         [ 1. -1.j,  3. -3.j]],

        [[ 4. -4.j,  6. -6.j],
         [ 5. -5.j,  7. -7.j]]],


       [[[ 8. -8.j, 10.-10.j],
         [ 9. -9.j, 11.-11.j]],

        [[12.-12.j, 14.-14.j],
         [13.-13.j, 15.-15.j]]],


       [[[16.-16.j, 18.-18.j],
         [17.-17.j, 19.-19.j]],

        [[20.-20.j, 22.-22.j],
         [21.-21.j, 23.-23.j]]]])
```

and AH

```
array([[[[ 0. -0.j,  2. -2.j],
         [ 1. -1.j,  3. -3.j]],

        [[ 4. -4.j,  6. -6.j],
         [ 5. -5.j,  7. -7.j]]],


       [[[ 8. -8.j, 10.-10.j],
         [ 9. -9.j, 11.-11.j]],

        [[12.-12.j, 14.-14.j],
         [13.-13.j, 15.-15.j]]],


       [[[16.-16.j, 18.-18.j],
         [17.-17.j, 19.-19.j]],

        [[20.-20.j, 22.-22.j],
         [21.-21.j, 23.-23.j]]]])
```

Which, I believe, is what you expected

Applied to your F (assuming of course that `j=1j`)

```
F.swapaxes(-1,2).conj()
⇒
array([[[[1.-2.j, 1.-2.j],
         [2.+1.j, 2.+1.j]],

        [[0.-0.j, 0.-0.j],
         [2.-1.j, 3.+1.j]]],


       [[[1.-2.j, 1.-2.j],
         [2.+1.j, 2.+1.j]],

        [[0.-0.j, 0.-0.j],
         [2.-1.j, 3.+1.j]]],


       [[[1.-2.j, 1.-2.j],
         [2.+1.j, 2.+1.j]],

        [[0.-0.j, 0.-0.j],
         [2.-1.j, 3.+1.j]]]])
```